# A Circuit dimming high power inductive load ( 10kw - 50 kw )

Tags: dimming

I need a circuit for dimming high power inductive load ( 10kw - 50 kw ) with protection for load short circuit .
for example dimming high pressure sodium lamps .

Comment: Could I suggest that you employ a specialist electronics consultant/company to supply you with a proven design and fully tested equipment for the specific high pressure sodium lights.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply not a do-it-yourself project.  If you have to ask here, you shouldn't touch this.  Get a professional with experience at this power level to do this, and of course be prepared to pay a real professional rate.  This is not for amatuers.